# Curve fit erro : The number of func parameters=3 must not exceed the number of data points=2

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy

I have a smiple function to find the curve according to out data points,

```
def dv_partial(df: pd.DataFrame) -> float:
    
    y_d = (df['high'] - df['low'] / 2).to_list()
    x_d = list(range(1, len(df) + 1))
    func = lambda x, a, b, c: (a * (x ** 2)) + (b * x) + c
    (a_p, b_p, c_p), _ = curve_fit(func, x_d, y_d, p0=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
```

But I get the error as :

> The number of func parameters=3 must not exceed the number of data
> points=2

I think I'm passing the correct parameters

I have also changed p0 from list[] to tuple (), but didn't work

Update:
It was because of the length of df, as it's length was less than 3 sometimes

Comment: That code works for me. Please check whether `df` is of length > 2.

Comment: It's not complaining `p0` being list or tuple.  `p0` is clearly length 3, right.  What is `number of data points=2`?  You don't tell us anything about `df`.  Did you even check it yourself?, or rather `x_d` and `y_d` that you derived from it?

Comment: Show the full error message, and tell us about the inputs.

Comment: Does curve fit not work if the number of parameters is > number of data?